# Substitutions on sharepoint lists for the time of vacation

Tags: list, workflow

I faced such a situation, one of manager is leaving for a long vacation, so we need to assign his tasks to the substitutes. The substitution should be only for the time of his absence. When he returns all tasks should be assigned to him back.

Do you have any ideas how to do it mass and quickly on SP lists with active workflows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to search for other solutions like Nintex, WEBCON or K2. They usually offer wide range of functionalities and low-coding. I’m currently testing a trial solution from WEBCON, but more in terms of creating workflows from scratch than modifying existing ones and it seems to be fine so far

Answer (score 2):

Instead of giving an individual (Manager) as an approver, give it a Group (SharePoint Group\AD Group). During your manager`s absence, substitute will be added to that group, and once he is back, remove that substitute from the group. That is how I planned my workflow architecture. Hope this should help for yours as well.

Comment: many thanks for your advice, but what if tasks are already assigned to people not a group? At this moment I can also hardly imagine creating groups for all managers who would need substitutions in the future. There must be some kind of solution as it’s a quite typical situation for each company, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Running workflows can not be assigned to other users.
You can update the emailaddress within the userprofile so the notifications will be sent to the correct person, but the substitue still needs the credentials of the manager to execute on its behalf

Comment: '@bonm014, the problem indeed is with credentials, besides I don't want substitue receives all SP notifications